# Не работает вывод ошибок discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
@client.command (pass_context = True)
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members= True)
async def ban (ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason):
    await ctx.channel.purge (limit =1) #тут есть ошибка. Если что поменяй 1 на бесконечность
    
    lol = discord.Embed(title = 'Пользователь забанен!', color = 0x9400D3 )
    lol.add_field(name = 'Модератор / админ:', value = ctx.message.author.mention, inline = False)
    lol.add_field(name = 'Нарушитель:', value = member.mention, inline = False)
    lol.add_field(name= 'Причина:', value = reason, inline = False)
    lol.set_thumbnail(url = 'https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2020/11/27/74c6f0135d52e0f6f02f649184dcfef4-full.jpg')
    lol.set_footer (text = f'Вызвано: {ctx.message.author}', icon_url = ctx.message.author.avatar_url)
    await ctx.send(embed = lol)
    await member.ban( reason = reason)
    await member.send(f'Вы забанены по причине "{reason}"!')
    #await ctx.send(f'Данный пользователь нарушил правила сервера и был забанен {member.mention }.')
@ban.error
async def inform_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        b = discord.Embed(title = 'Ошибка!', color =0xff060e)
        b.add_field(name = 'Причина ошибки:', value = 'Введите пользователя, которого хотите забанить и причину!', inline = False)
        b.add_field(name = 'Пример использования команды:', value = 'lu.ban @user reason', inline = False)
        b.set_image(url = 'https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2020/11/26/732cf19905aad1238e61fe222a31e615-full.png')
        await ctx.send(embed = b)
@ban.error
async def clear_errorqw(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, MissingPermissions):
        b = discord.Embed(title = 'Ошибка!', color =0xff060e)
        b.add_field(name = 'Причина ошибки:', value = 'У вас нету нужных прав для управления этой командой!', inline = False)
        b.set_image(url = 'https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2020/11/26/732cf19905aad1238e61fe222a31e615-full.png')
        await ctx.send(embed = b)
```

При разрешении "banned_users" бот не хочет выводить ошибку. Если поставить разрешение "administrator", то он будет выводить ошибку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перед тем, как опробовать рабочий код, прошу обратить внимание на следующие замечания:

1. `@client.command(pass_context = True)` - параметр `pass_context` в новых версиях указывать не нужно, достаточно просто `@client.command()`
2. Вы пытаетесь отправить сообщение пользователю уже после того, как баните его:

   `await member.ban( reason = reason)`

   `await member.send(f'Вы забанены по причине "{reason}"!')`

   В этом случае, скорее всего получится так, что у пользователя и бота не останется общих серверов и бот просто не сможет отправить ему сообщение о бане.
3. Отлов ошибок команды `ban()` лучше сместить в одну функцию и расположить проверку условий ошибки в правильном порядке. То есть - сначала проверяем есть ли у пользователя права на бан, а уже потом на наличие упущенных аргументов и т.п. Это нужно для того, чтобы при упущенных аргументах от пользователя без прав на бан участника, бот сразу указывал ему на то, что он не может так делать.
4. Также стоит разбить проверку ошибок в команде на *"Отсутствие причины"* и *"Отсутствие пользователя"*, так как дискорд это позволяет.
5. Бот мог не выдавать вам ошибку, потому что ее нет в списке исключений. Например, как вы уже отметили, в строке `await ctx.channel.purge (limit =1)` есть ошибка. Скорее всего это происходит потому, что у бота нет прав на *"Управление сообщениями"*. Еще раз посмотрите, чтобы были все нужные права, которые используются в функции
6. На всякий случай, выдайте боту намерения (`intents`). Скорее всего они понадобятся для работы с участниками серверов.

   `intents = discord.Intents.all()`

   `client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)`
7. Ну и наконец, учтите, что бот может выгонять и банить только тех участников, которые в списке ролей находятся ниже роли бота. Это важно, так как в противном случае, бот напишет, что забанил пользователя, а на деле участник останется на сервере.

**На картинке указано неправильно расположение роли бота с правами на бан участников.**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

### Код:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN = 'TOKEN'

intents = discord.Intents.all()

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members = True)
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit = 1)
    
    lol = discord.Embed(title = 'Пользователь забанен!', color = 0x9400D3 )
    lol.add_field(name = 'Модератор / админ:', value = ctx.message.author.mention, inline = False)
    lol.add_field(name = 'Нарушитель:', value = member.mention, inline = False)
    lol.add_field(name= 'Причина:', value = reason, inline = False)
    lol.set_thumbnail(url = 'https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2020/11/27/74c6f0135d52e0f6f02f649184dcfef4-full.jpg')
    lol.set_footer (text = f'Вызвано: {ctx.message.author}', icon_url = ctx.message.author.avatar_url)
    await ctx.send(embed = lol)
    await member.send(f'Вы забанены по причине "{reason}"!')
    await member.ban( reason = reason)
    #await ctx.send(f'Данный пользователь нарушил правила сервера и был забанен {member.mention }.')

@ban.error
async def clear_errorqw(ctx, error):

    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        b = discord.Embed(title = 'Ошибка!', color =0xff060e)
        b.add_field(name = 'Причина ошибки:', value = 'У вас нету нужных прав для управления этой командой!', inline = False)
        b.set_image(url = 'https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2020/11/26/732cf19905aad1238e61fe222a31e615-full.png')
        await ctx.send(embed = b)

    if isinstance(error, commands.errors.MemberNotFound):
        b = discord.Embed(title = 'Ошибка!', color =0xff060e)
        b.add_field(name = 'Причина ошибки:', value = 'Не указано имя пользователя', inline = False)
        b.add_field(name = 'Пример использования команды:', value = 'lu.ban @user reason', inline = False)
        b.set_image(url = 'https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2020/11/26/732cf19905aad1238e61fe222a31e615-full.png')
        await ctx.send(embed = b)

    if isinstance(error, commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument):
        b = discord.Embed(title = 'Ошибка!', color =0xff060e)
        b.add_field(name = 'Причина ошибки:', value = 'Не указана причина', inline = False)
        b.add_field(name = 'Пример использования команды:', value = 'lu.ban @user reason', inline = False)
        b.set_image(url = 'https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2020/11/26/732cf19905aad1238e61fe222a31e615-full.png')
        await ctx.send(embed = b)

client.run(TOKEN)
```

---

**Результат:**

*В виде ссылок, потому что ответ и без картинок слишком длинный :)*

[Ошибка: Нет прав для выполнения команды](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCqux.png)

[Ошибка: Не указана причина бана](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPERh.png)

[Ошибка: Не указано имя пользователя](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OgYA.png)

[Успешно забанен](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQTwS.png)